# "NameError: name 'SQLAlchemy' is not defined" despite installing with pip

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to run a python script that implements SQLAlchemy. However it is outputting an error `NameError: name 'SQLAlchemy' is not defined` I installed SQLAlchemy with 'pip install sqlalchemy' and thought I imported it correctly at the top of the script.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sqlalchemy

engine = create_engine('sqlite:////Users/Desktop/practice/database.db')
db = SQLAlchemy(engine)


class newsPosts(db.Model):

    newsSite = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    title = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    url = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=True)


def main():
    print("hello world")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the entire error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrapeNews.py", line 13, in <module>
    db = SQLAlchemy(engine)
NameError: name 'SQLAlchemy' is not defined
```

Comment: You imported `sqlalchemy`, not `SQLAlchemy`.  Capitalization matters.

Comment: Doesnt work, apparently only flask-sqlalchemy uses this module. Let me know if you find a way to implement sqlalchemy normally

Answer (score 1):

You have an import error. You import the `sqlalchemy` module, but no `SQLAlchemy` class. If that class is part of the module, you either have to

```
 from sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

or refer to it as

```
 db = sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy(engine)
```

However, I don't remember a such class existing in the module. A class with that name exists in the `flask-alchemy` package.

Comment: Yes, I tried this but it says it does not exist. I am used to using flask-sqlalchemy. Do you happen to know what the proper way to implement regular sqlalchemy would be?

Comment: @Greg: The connection setup in regular sqlalchemy is slightly more complicated. I think you can directly do `engine.execute("select * from table")` but it's not very efficient. You need to see code examples here http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html. Or, you could just use flask-alchemy, which works fine even without using flask itself (which you are probably gonna need eventually, anyway)

Answer (score 1):

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

Comment: Consider restating your answer as a "replace the first two lines in your script with..." followed by your properly formatted answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `SQLAlchemy` in `sqlalchemy`. That is in flask-sqlalchemy, as others wrote.

The way to define a model using *"normal"* SQLAlchemy is best shown in their [tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html). In short, your code to define table `newsPosts` should be:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, String

Base = declarative_base()

class newsPosts(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'newsPosts'  # the actual table name in DB

    newsSite = Column(String(128), nullable=False)
    title = Column(String(128), nullable=False)
    date = Column(String(128), nullable=False)
    url = Column(String(128), nullable=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, zvone. Do you happen to know if there is a way to provide a filepath to the given sqlite file? I will try to find this feature through your provided tutorial link as well

Comment: @Greg Define the engine, just as you did. There, the path to the file will be defined. Then, you'll have to create a session and use it for your queries and `commit` the session in the end. It is not complicated, but you should google it to get familiar with the concept.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can import correctly

```
 from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

and also you are working in virtual environment or venv and you have already installed sqlalchemy then you have to again install it in virtual environment

```
pip install flask-sqlalchemy
```

The above command is to install sqlalchemy